# Change the quality of the image (without changing the resolution)

Tags: android, linux, image, bash, imagemagick

I found this command

Resize an image with improved quality:

```
$ convert input.png -colorspace RGB +sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 \ 
-define filter:filter=Sinc -define filter:window=Jinc -define filter:lobes=3 \ 
-resize 400% -sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 -colorspace sRGB output.png
```

But I need something else, I need a command to decrease the image quality.
For example if the input.png is 100pix x 100pix resolution and 100KB size
I want to make an output.png image with the same resolution but lower quality, let say 50KB

how can I do this ?

(My original problem is the limitation to 50KB images, and all I want to do is convert all my images below 50KB size).

I hope this is easy to solve but could not figured out on my own.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)? It won't change the image's quality, but will try to compress the hell out of it. If you're trying to reduce _file size_, quality won't necessarily change that with PNG-type compression. Unless you're trying to reduce the number of colors overall and index the palette... that might work.

Comment: I do not know what should I do :), I know it is possible to lower the quality of an image and to have lower image size but I do not know how to do it with shell

Comment: You might try the -depth parameter on convert.  I found that a `convert file.png -depth 4` reduced my PNG file size by around 50%.

Comment: For pngcrush, I usually use `pngcrush -rem alla -brute -reduce input.png output.png`. It varies by file, but you can get some serious reductions. `-bit_depth 4` can get you more, similar to `-depth 4` with convert, but you will lose actual quality for some images.

Comment: How does this question relate to Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert the image to a lower sampling rate. ImageMagick has an article on [Transformations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#pixelate) that cover a few options.

```bash
convert input.png -sample 25% -scale 400% output.png
```

Results:

```bash
input.png  PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 27.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
output.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 225c 6.58KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image: input.png] input.png

[image: output.png] output.png